# Copy a matrix between Maple and Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, maple

How can a given (4x4) matrix be copied from Maple to MATLAB?

Comment: Are you sure matlab is returning a wrong result ?

Comment: I'm very surprised as well that Matlab should return a wrong result on matrix algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Maple, you should be able to use the [ExportMatrix](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=ExportMatrix) command to produce a file (from numeric Matrices or Vectors) which Matlab can read.

Maple 15 and later allow for export to a binary file format that Matlab can read. Older versions such a 14, 13, etc could export with that command only to ASCII format files that Matlab could read.